The input line is too long and the syntax of command is incorrect while running the zookeeper in window. While running the kafka zookeeper in local
"The input line is too long" and "The syntax of the command is incorrect" while running Zookeeper on Windows
I am trying to start Zookeeper on my Windows system using Kafka, but I encounter the following errors:
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties

The input line is too long and the syntax of command is incorrect while running the zookeeper in window.:
Solution :- 1. Make sure the JAVA_NOME path is set.
2. Direct download and extract under c drive and rename the folder as kafka.
C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
